# Can Hypothesis shrink an failing test case which was not found by Hypothesis?

Tags: python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

Nicholas Chammas [wrote](https://groups.google.com/g/hypothesis-users/c/899ZQWne5Fs/m/Rt0y8dSzBQAJ) on the hypothesis-users mailing list:

> A user reported a bug in a function and provided a reproduction. I decided to write a test for this function to see if Hypothesis could find the same bug.
>
> The test looks like this:
>
> ```
> @given(data=lists(tuples(floats())))
> def test_percentile(data):
>     ...
> ```
>
> I’ve run this test with up to 100,000 examples, but Hypothesis is not finding this bug. A very specific set of circumstances that I do not understand need to line up precisely for this bug to reveal itself.
>
> I am now trying to figure out something different: Given a known failing example, can Hypothesis help me shrink it to its simplest form?
>
> The reproduction provided by the user is a list that’s 373 elements long. I managed to manually shrink it down to 45 elements.
>
> Is there any way to get Hypothesis to shrink the known failing example even further?

What is the answer to that? Can Hypothesis shrink a failing test case it didn't find?

*(I've copied the question here so the answer can be updated over time.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis can only shrink examples that it generated, but you can improve your odds of finding a known failure by...

1. running for even longer (e.g. overnight) - computer time is cheaper than your time
2. [using `target()` to 'aim at'](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#targeted-example-generation) the known failure can make the search much more efficient

---

This is a fundamental consequence of the way Hypothesis is designed: [both generation and shrinking work on the same underlying representation, and because strategies can include arbitrary Python code it's impossible in general to "run them backwards" and turn your test case into IR.

(It *is* possible to [run generators backwards](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3607842) in restricted settings, and in principle this could be implemented for simple Hypothesis strategies - but I really dislike interfaces which only work in easy cases.  We use a similar trick in our internals though.)

Nonetheless, "shrink user-reported failing cases" has been on my personal wishlist for literally years now - `@example(<your value here>).shrink()` would be a lovely interface (fail if we can't reach it; [dump a patch](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#v6-75-0) if we shrink it).  The easiest implementation would be to automatically derive some `target()` metrics as described above; more complex and efficient to to supplement that with an analytic solution in cases where we can.  [Support for symbolic execution](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/3086) might also be useful, although we're speculating about combining wishlist ideas now :-)

Comment: Thank you for the interesting references. No dice with `target()`, but restricting the length of the `data` list to the length of the known failing example did eventually guide Hypothesis to finding it. I then progressively allowed shorter and shorter lists, which led Hypothesis to shrink the example from a list of 45 entries to a list of 14.

Comment: One idea I initially considered was to write a [stateful test](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stateful.html) that would attempt to mutate the provided example in ways that simplified it while trying to recreate the failure. A bit heavy handed, but perhaps that would have also worked.

Comment: At that point I'd reach for https://github.com/DRMacIver/shrinkray, a tool for shrinking arbitrary text (but especially structured stuff like code or data) with respect to an arbitrary predicate (ie shell script).  Glad you got it working though!